# How can I that send commands with synchronized?

Tags: android, synchronized

I have a class about serial port or bluetooth by android.The class has a method called 
CommandSender(String CommandText);

There are many forms or threads could call the method.How can I do that:
If the method called by once that execute the method immediately,
If several forms or threads called the method, just sleep 2 seconds before/after called.

please give code details.
Thand you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can just use

```
public synchronized void CommandSender(String CommandText) { }
```

but this will not provide a sleep of 2 seconds that you need. If you really need 2 second sleep then you have to make your own implementation.

```
public class BluetoothUtils
{
    private static boolean isLocked = false;

    public void CommandSender(String CommandText)
    {
        while(isLocked)
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000); // sleep for 2 seconds
        }
        CommandSenderInternal(CommandText);
    }

    private synchronized void CommandSenderInternal(String CommandText)
    {
        isLocked = true;
        try
        {
            // Your implementation here
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
             isLocked = false;
        }
    }
}
```